# Вызов процедуры Оракл через питон

Tags: python, oracle

Есть процедура на оракл, мне нужно вызвать ее через питон.
Моя процедура:

```
create or replace procedure Test(refcursor out sys_refcursor) is
    begin
    open refcursor for
        select * from testtable;
end Test;
```

Код питона для вызова:

```
outVal = cur.var(int)
cur.callproc('Test')
print(outVal.getvalue())
```

Моя ошибка:

> cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
> PLS-00905: object test is invalid
> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
> PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: ну и что? у вас что-то не работает?

Comment: это вам ответ: https://support.microsoft.com/ru-kz/help/965939/ora-06550-line-1-column-7-pls-00201-identifier-chart-must-be-declared